# What can correctly follow the $d$ in an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, differential

I have seen all sorts of things follow the $d$ in integrals, including $dy$, $dx$, and $d^2x$. Does just about anything go? Can I follow the $d$ with an expression, as in
$∫ (4x + 17)$$d(4x + 17)$?

Comment: Stieltjes integrals integrate with respect to (well-behaved) functions, so I think the short answer for you is yes.

Comment: This is a major part of measure-theory , and integration with respect to measures. $df(x)$ where $f$ is a function (or $d^2g(x)$ etc.) can eventually be interpreted as measures with respect to which certain functions can be integrated. The integral written in the body falls under this category. Unfortunately, a discussion on this is perhaps too broad, but someone could volunteer, perhaps after deriving some more context so as to make their answer more specific to the situation and not confuse our OP.

Answer (score 0):

Given $y$ is some well behaved function of $x$, then $dy=\frac{dy}{dx}dx$. So as long as your function $y$ that you put there is differentiable on the range of the integral, what $y$ is doesn't matter. If $y=4x+17$, then as mentioned in a comment, $dy=d(4x+17)=\frac{d(4x+17)}{dx}dx=4dx$.

$y=4x+17$ is differentiable on the full set of reals so you need to have no worries about this, if your function $y$ has singularities at $0$ or some other value, or some other non-differentiable points, you must be more careful.